# Why does this XML not render in the browser the way I want?

Tags: php, rss

I want to use php to create RSS from mysql. I can see the content in the page source code. But I can not see the item part in Web Browser(IE, Firefox or Opera). the Web Browser just show

`Your RSS Feed Name or Website Name

A description of your feed or site.`

```
<?PHP
require_once ('mysql_connect.php'); 
    //SET XML HEADER
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //CONSTRUCT RSS FEED HEADERS
    $output = '<rss version="2.0">';
    $output .= '<channel>';
    $output .= '<title>Your RSS Feed Name or Website Name</title>';
    $output .= '<description>A description of your feed or site.</description>';
    $output .= '<link>http://www.yoursite.com/</link>';
    $output .= '<copyright>Your copyright details</copyright>';

    //BODY OF RSS FEED
    mysql_select_db("rss", $db);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rss limit 15",$db);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '<item>';
                $output .= '<title>'. $row['title'] .'</title>';
                $output .= '<description>'. $row['content'] .'</description>';
                $output .= '<link>'. $row['link'] .'</link>';
                $output .= '<pubDate></pubDate>';
            $output .= '</item> ';
        }
    mysql_close($db); 
    //CLOSE RSS FEED
    $output .= '</channel>';
    $output .= '</rss>';

    //SEND COMPLETE RSS FEED TO BROWSER
    echo($output);

?>
```

the xml source looks like:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Your RSS Feed Name or Website Name</title>
<description>A description of your feed or site.</description>
<link>http://www.yoursite.com/</link>
<copyright>Your copyright details</copyright>
  <item>
    <title>MILAN, ITALY - SEPTEMBER 26: Models walk the runway at Emi&hellip</title>       
    <description>Date: Sep 26, 2009 7:45 PMNumber of Comments on Photo:0View Photo&hellip;</description>
    <link>http://picasaweb.google.com/roxyluvtony/KendraSpears#5551895410815389042</link>
    <pubDate></pubDate>
  </item>
  ...
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: "Why does the browser not render the output of this PHP the way I want?" is not as good a question as "Why does this PHP output this XML instead of the XML I want?" or "Why does this XML not render in the browser the way I want?"

Comment: @jnpcl, like this `<rss version="2.0"><channel><title>Your RSS Feed Name or Website Name</title><description>A description of your feed or site.</description><link>http://www.yoursite.com/</link><copyright>Your copyright details</copyright><item><title>MILAN, ITALY - SEPTEMBER 26: Models walk the runway at Emi&hellip;</title><description>Date: Sep 26, 2009 7:45 PMNumber of Comments on Photo:0View Photo&hellip;</description><link>http://picasaweb.google.com/roxyluvtony/KendraSpears#5551895410815389042</link><pubDate></pubDate></item> `

Comment: @David Dorward, ok, I edited.

Comment: @yuli you should edit the XML into the question, it is very hard to read that way.... Does it pass RSS validation? SHouldn't you be sending a RSS specific content type?

Comment: At first glance, it's not valid XML because of the `&hellip;` entity in your `<title>` and `<description>` nodes. Wrap those strings with a `<![CDATA[tag]]>` and try again.

Comment: http://feedvalidator.org/ will highlight some problems with that

Comment: @jnpcl, Thanks, I add `<![CDATA[tag]]>` and now I can see the item part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving my comment to an Answer...*

it's not valid XML because of the `&hellip;` entity in your `<title>` and `<description>` nodes.

Wrap those strings with a `<![CDATA[tag]]>` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching a regular array instead of an associative array. It should be:

`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`

The difference is `mysql_fetch_array()` will fetch with integers as indexes (`$row[0]`), and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` gives you names (`$row['title']`).

Comment: In that case there is probably something wrong with your query. Try running it in mysql command line or phpMyAdmin to see what it returns.

Comment: As yuli stated in their question, they can see the content by viewing the source of the rendered page.

Comment: thanks for your help, the main problem is I should add `<![CDATA[tag]]>` in my item's tags.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to your content type? Try `Content-Type: application/rss+xml` rather than `Content-type: text/xml`